# Adding graduated color to line based on data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, qgis-2.6, color-ramp

I have a line that I would like to color based on some data points that I have along its path. I'm not sure the best way to go about this.

Should I try to break the line up into many segments?

Then I guess I would need to join the point data to each line segment?

I'm using qGIS 2.6.

I have a gas pipe KML file that I want to change the color of depending on the flow of gas through the pipe at any given point. I can calculate the flow myself, then it is just a matter of incorporating that data into the map. The points on the pipe where I measure the flow are pretty much up to me, but they will not be regularly spaced. I've been tinkering around, but I'm sure you would have some better ideas.

Comment: Yes, break the line at points http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003w000000 (the single line has to have the same symbol throughout)... the real fun starts with getting the values from the points to the line segments. How do the points relate to the lines? is it start, end, maxof, minof, average?